# How to show configurable product as related product with their options in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

I'm currently doing a webcommerce web site with Magento for a client. The problem is that when I add a configurable product as a related product, it shows the product but there is no checkbox. I have read that in magento when the related product is a configurable one it won't show the options and the checkbox. Is there a way to fix that ?

Thanks

Comment: After some googling I think this link can be very helpfull : http://subesh.com.np/2009/12/custom-options-product-magento/

Comment: Once you have the customs options under your related product you just have to override the addaction to take care of the options : http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.com/2010/11/magento-overwrite-cart-controller-add.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not without customisation. The key here is that a configurable product has to be configured, ie. select a size/colour etc.

You wouldn't be able to add the product by ticking the box, in the same way you cannot add a configurable product from the category list view - because you need to go to the product page to select the option for the configurable product.

If you look at some of the Ajax add-to-cart extensions, they get round this by providing a light box to select the configurable options (so that you do not have to change page). So you could code a similar action for when someone ticks the box (on select, present a popup with the various configurations).

Comment: I'll look into that. Right now I can see the select box and choose the option I want I just need to add the product with the option. Or simply as you say use a ajax add-to-cart. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could anyone recommend a free and a paid-for add-on that can handle this? Afaik Magento add-ins don't have an easy way to uninstall so this limits me from trying too many plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this with customisation. Rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related` and change the `_addProductAttributesAndPrice()`-method:

```
/**
 * Add all attributes and apply pricing logic to products collection
 * to get correct values in different products lists.
 * E.g. crosssells, upsells, new products, recently viewed
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
 */
protected function _addProductAttributesAndPrices(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection)
{
    return $collection
//        ->addMinimalPrice()
//        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ;
}
```

When you comment the price-related methods, the configurable products passes the filtering process.

But keep in mind Ben's answer: you will not be able to add the product by ticking the checkbox: you need to set some options. That's why this method is good when you just want to use the related products-functionality for a way to create links to other products (like upsells do), instead of a way to directly add 2 or more products with one click (what related products are intended for).